# How to change windows service name after creating it

Tags: windows, windows-services

I have created windows service for tomcat server and it is running well but now I want to change service name without deleting it.

so is there any cmd\GUI steps to change service name?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

[@bfhd's answer](https://superuser.com/a/975838/490167) will work if you just want to change the Display Name (which is what's shown in the list in `Services.msc`, but is not the "real" service name (which is the name of the registry key containing the service information, and used in APIs like `OpenService`). The Remarks section of [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683229(v=vs.85).aspx) talks about service names vs. display names a bit more.

Unfortunately, there's no official way to change a service's name. However, it is probably possible, if you absolutely *must* rename the service instead of just re-installing it under the new name for some reason. Do the following:

1. Stop the service. You will probably confuse the service control manager if you do this on a running service. (You may confuse it anyhow, this is very hacky.)
2. Open `regedit.exe` (Registry Editor).
3. Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services` and find the subkey with your service's name.
4. Right-click the key you found in step #3, and select Rename. Enter the new name for the service.
5. Restart the computer. `Services.exe`, the process that hosts the service control manager, won't see the change unless you do; attempts to start the renamed process (or otherwise interact with it at all, actually) will fail.

I make no promise of this working. It's probably worth trying, though, if for some reason just reinstalling the service under a new name is so unacceptable.

If you must do this programmatically, there *may* exist a function `RegRenameKey` that can do the fourth step above for you. I stress *may* exist because, so far as I can tell, this function is completely unofficial; it's not in MSDN and there's precious little info about it. The only thing I found, other than the Windows headers (which have the prototype, and indicate that it's only on Vista - NT6.0 - and newer), is a [Sysinternals forum post](http://forum.sysinternals.com/about-regrenamekey_topic19717.html), which indicates that it calls an NT syscall (also undocumented). The function prototype, from `WinReg.h`, is

```
WINADVAPI
LSTATUS
APIENTRY
RegRenameKey(
    _In_ HKEY hKey,
    _In_opt_ LPCWSTR lpSubKeyName,
    _In_ LPCWSTR lpNewKeyName
);
```

Comment: WIN10Pro: it does not work. Shut down, reboot, nothing. Name is changed in the registry, yes, but in Services display, old name remains.

Comment: @Echeban By "Services display" do you mean the name listed in the Services management console (`services.msc`) main list view? That's the Display Name, not the service name. You can change that either in the registry or using the command line, but it's not the thing the instructions above change. The instructions posted are for changing the service's actual name - not the same as the display name - and I tested it on Windows 10 Enterprise. You can see the actual Service Name in `services.msc` but only by displaying the details ("Properties") of an individual service.

Comment: Using Windows PowerShell, there _is_ an official way to change a service's _display name_ and other properties. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-service?view=powershell-7.1 or web search for "how to change windows service powershell".

Comment: @Suncat2000 That's potentially useful information, but it isn't really relevant to this answer (which is about changing the actual service name, something powershell's `Set-Service` cmdlet **can not do**). You might have wanted to create a new answer?

Comment: [RegRenameKey appears to be documented now](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regrenamekey)

Answer (score 45):

The Windows command line program to change services is "sc".

Here's the Microsoft reference page: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490995.aspx

To change the display name of a service you can run:

```
sc config "Old service name" displayname= "New service name"
```

To change the executable you can run:

```
sc config "Service name" binpath= "C:\path\to\executable\here"
```

For both of those commands, make sure you have a space between the = and the new name (ie. `displayname= "New Name"`, **NOT** `displayname="New Name"`)

Comment: If your tomcat uses the monitor program there will be a `[oldservicename]w.exe` on your drive. Don´t forget to change that name

Comment: This changes the service's display name and not the service name.

Comment: Service name and Display Name are two different things. Display Name, you see it at first glance in the services window. Service name, you have to do Properties to see it.

Comment: sc config "Service" displayname= "My Service" does not work 
Set-Content : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'displayname='.
At line:1 char:1
+ sc config "Service" displayname= "My Servic ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Content], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetContentCommand

Comment: @Echeban if you are running it in powershell, you need to use sc.exe.